# Unable to add git repository in XCode

Tags: xcode, git

In "Source control" panel XCode shows "No working copies". Options to add files to git, commit are disabled, no "M" modifiers and etc.

I have tried to create fresh new project with "Create empty git repository" checkbox checked, and also tried to add git to existing project through "Source control" -> "New git repositories..." – same result

I have also tried to delete .git folder and recreate the git repository, no success

[image]

Comment: Is the Enable Source Control checkbox selected in Xcode's Source Control preferences? If you create a git repo with a new project, can you access the repository in another app like SourceTree?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an issue

I put my working folder under /usr/local/srv/.., so there was permission issue.

At the time not sure how's that connected to only git repo bug, but after directory transfer to ~/Documents, issue has gone